# How to color a given pixel within a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

In a BufferedImage, you can get the color of a given pixel using:

```
image.getRBG(x, y)
```

But is there an equivalent method for setting the rbg color of a given pixel, e.g:

```
image.setRBG(x, y, rbgCode)
```

I'm doing some image manipulation, and simply want to paint certain pixels red so I can track the path that my algorithm took while processing the image.

Comment: -1, Did you read the API?

Comment: @camickr Yes, guess I missed it somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like [`BufferedImage#setRGB(x, y, rgb)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29)?

For example

```
image.setRGB(x, y, Color.RED.getRGB());
```

Comment: The JavaDocs should always be your first call of reference...;)